# Creating a "function menu" to Google Sheet that will work in Android Mobile App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a drop-down list of subject codes (All, ICT101, ICT103, MATH105, PHY109, HUM111 and so on) in a particular cell for example A4. By default the selection is 'All' in A4 cell. I created custom menus but those are not supported in Google Sheets Mobile App.

Now if there is any change in A4, the function refreshSheet() needs to be executed. For instance, if I select ICT101, the refreshSheet() will be executed, if I select MATH105, the same refreshSheet() will be executed and so on. But if I select 'All' again in cell A4, it will do Nothing. How to solve it?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B1') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      this[e.value]();
      e.range.clear();
    }
  }
}
    
function refreshSheet() { 
  //this function codes are working fine by using custom menus;
}
```

Comment: If there is "All" in A4 and you select  "All" again, it's not a edit. Add a empty selection/ empty space as default selection in data validation

Comment: In fact, I need 'All' as a default for analytics. Even when the function refreshSheet() will be executed, it will reset the cell A4 to 'All' at the end. How to code it?

Comment: Add a empty space or a explicit "none" to the list top

Comment: Is the code ok? How to link the trigger with the refreshSheet() as in the drop down list there are  only subject codes

Comment: Call `refreshSheet()` from onEdit.. Code doesn't seem to be ok, but since you said, it's working  I went along with it. If you're copying code from site,  you should attribute the author of the code.

Comment: Please note that my code for refreshSheet is ok. But just need to confirm onEdit() and it's linkage to refreshSheet().

Comment: Your question seemed to imply that you are indeed calling `refreshSheet` from your `onEdit`, even though that's not the case. What's your issue? Do you need help "attaching" `refreshSheet` to your `onEdit`, or your problem is you'd like `refreshSheet` to fire if the previous option (`All`) is selected (so no edit is actually made)?

Comment: The dropdown menu consists several values like All, IT101, PHY102, CS301 and so on. What I want is, if any value except All is selected, the refreshSheet will be executed. In case of All, nothing will be done. That's All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to execute the function `refreshSheet` whenever there is a change on the selected option in the dropdown (which, in this example, is located in `A4`), **as long as this selected option is not `All`**.

If that's the case, you just need to modify your `onEdit` function to this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'A4' && e.range.getValue() !== "All") {
    refreshSheet();
  }
}
```

The function checks that edited cell is `A4` and edited value is not `All`, using the information provided by the [onEdit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).

#### Note:

- Depending on what `refreshSheet()` does (specially if it calls services that require authorization), you might need to [install the `onEdit` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) (see [Simple Triggers > Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)).